# Why does the word "dodgeball" focus on the defensive skills instead of the offensive skills?

Tags: etymology, sports

I'm a Dutch user, and in Dutch, dodgeball is called "trefbal" (literally hitball), referring to what the person with the ball is trying to do. In English, Dodgeball refers to the action that the targeted person is trying to do. I've looked on Wikipedia, and other countries are doing similarly: French calls it "Ballon aux prisonnier", which refers to the local variety where someone who gets hit gets a second chance to attack from the other side. I've also seen translations that come down to chieftainball and hunterball. both of these are likely references to the offensive party

I don't know why English is different in that the same game is named after the defending player, not the offensive player. Is there a particular reason for this in etymology?

Comment: Because it's such good practice for life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really no rhyme or reason to how "_____ball" sports are named. Dodgeball is named after the defensive action, kickball is named after the offensive action, basketball is named after where you put the ball, baseball is named after where you run after you hit the ball, football is named after the body part that comes in contact with the ball, etc.

Comment: Or in the case of American football, named after the ... it's just the name, OK?

Comment: I assume it's because you kick the ball to punt it? Or maybe because the length of the ball is about the length of a human foot?

Comment: Nicole: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/341/why-is-american-football-called-football

Comment: It is, first and foremost, a child's game, named by children.  They did not consult dictionaries to name it, but simply chose (no doubt over the course of decades) the name that seemed to fit best.  (It would be better to ask why other languages call it "hitball".)

Answer (score 4):

In America the ***winner*** of *[dodgeball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgeball)* is the one who ***dodges*** best.

The most common schoolyard version is the pickup variation known as [Poisonball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dodgeball_variations):

> This variant of dodgeball is different from other dodgeball variations
>   due to the fact there is only one team, no form of resurrection and
>   the winner is an individual and not a team. It is normally played on a
>   small to medium sized arena (Like a basketball court) and between 1–10
>   balls are used. Two throwers get selected. Their job is to eliminate
>   as much players as they can by throwing the ball(s) at the players.The
>   players stay in the court and they have to try and stay alive by
>   dodging the ball(s) thrown at them. Once a player gets hit, they join
>   the throwers and have to try to eliminate more players using the
>   balls. Usually over time, more balls get introduced to decrease the
>   survival rate. The winner is the last man standing. In the Caribbean,
>   it is known as Dandy Shandy. It is a popular street game which is
>   played with a stuffed empty box more often used as a ball alternative
>   when an actual ball is not available.

I can only imagine how they would [demonize](http://priceonomics.com/how-dodgeball-became-americas-most-demonized-sport/) the game if it were called **hitball**:

> With trembling knees and sweaty palms, the requisite nerd cowers in a
>   dark corner of his school’s gymnasium. He bobbles back and forth with
>   uncertainty, as if running into invisible walls: nowhere to hide.
>
> A herd of ogreish seniors lumbers toward him now, arms cocked and
>   fully loaded. Our dear protagonist is a sitting duck at the mercy of a
>   teenage firing squad; in mere seconds, he’ll be pummeled by a barrage
>   of red rubber balls.
>
> As kids, most of us played the game; as adults, we seem to either look
>   back on dodgeball with warm nostalgia or unbridled terror. But at some
>   juncture, the game became the diabolical bastard of American
>   recreational activities, castigated by physical educators, pundits,
>   and the media. It has been denounced by local, state, and federal
>   organizations, and it is increasingly being banned by public schools.
>
> But how exactly did dodgeball morph into a scapegoat for sporting
>   cruelty?

Comment: Yes - I was thinking along the lines of that it was named for the objective...to win by being the best at dodging the ball.